# Error:Configurable attribute "copts" doesn't match this configuration When build tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

when I build tensorflow on Ubuntu,I met the error logs as follows:

```
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/ad1e09741bb4109fbc70ef8216b59ee2/external/nsync/BUILD:401:13: Configurable attribute "copts" doesn't match this configuration (would a default condition help?).
Conditions checked:
 @nsync//:android_arm
 @nsync//:android_arm64
 @nsync//:android_armeabi
 @nsync//:android_x86_32
 @nsync//:android_x86_64
 @nsync//:clang_macos_x86_64
 @nsync//:gcc_linux_aarch64
 @nsync//:gcc_linux_ppc64
 @nsync//:gcc_linux_x86_64_1
 @nsync//:gcc_linux_x86_64_2
 @nsync//:ios_x86_64
 @nsync//:msvc_windows_x86_64.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted.
```

the environment is Linux pine64 3.10.104-2-pine64-longsleep,it runs on armv8.with bazel 0.4.5 I build as in the instructions

```
bazel build -c opt --copt="-funsafe-math-optimizations" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Is anyone knows how to solve it ? I appreciate ever help, thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that bazel didn't recognize your cpu for `select` calls in nsync's BUILD. It happens here: https://github.com/google/nsync/blob/master/BUILD#L130. The fix would be either adding `"//conditions:default": [],` into all relevant selects, or adding another `config_setting` with your cpu value. Does bazel output your cpu value anywhere?